# Nonlinear diffusion (heat) equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Good day to all!
Let me consider  equation
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(f(u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)+g(u)$$
where $t\in(0,+\infty),x\in [a,b]$ and $f(u),g(u)$ are smooth bounded functions.

In addition, given:

initial conditions
$$u(x,0)=\varphi(x)$$

Neumann boundary condition
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg|_{x=a}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg|_{x=b}=0,$$
I have a few questions:

1. What numerical method can be chosen to solve this problem? Can we be sure that the chosen method will be convergent and stable for this equation.
2. What can we say about  Existence, Uniqueness and Stability of solution?
3. Can we transfer the answers of 2) to more general case

$$\frac{\partial \bf{u}}{\partial t}=\text{div}(f(\mathbf{ u})\cdot \text{grad}\,\mathbf{u})+g(\mathbf{u}),\,\,\, \text{where }\mathbf{u}=(u_1(x,y,t),u_2(x,y,t),u_3(x,y,t))$$
$$\mathbf{u}(x,y,0)\bigg|_\Omega=\mathbf{\Phi}(x,y),\,\,\,\,\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial \mathbf{n}}\bigg|_\Omega=0?$$

Comment: I've asked this question before, and it seems difficult to find materials on numerical approaches to this topic. I have previously used explicit finite difference methods to solve
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(f(u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right),
$$
where $f(u)$ was reasonably 'nice'. I still don't know any stability criterion or abourt existence/uniqueness of solutions though.

Comment: In my case, it can be specify $f(u)=\frac1{u}$ or $f(u)=\frac1{1+u^2}$.  I started to study spectral methods, as in the scientific literature they are often used to numerical solve nonlinear equations. However, it will be meaningless if the equation does not assert at least the existence and uniqueness of the solution.